# Find largest d in array such that a + b + c = d

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting

**Task**
You are given a sorted integer array arr. It contains several unique integers(negative, positive, or zero).

Your task is to find the largest d such that a + b + c = d, where a, b, c, and d are distinct elements of arr. If no such an element d found, return null.

**Example:**

For arr = [2,3,5,7,12], the output should be 12 (this array passes my function correctly)

For arr = [-100,-1,0,7,101], the output should be 0 (this one does not pass)

I could manage the positive numbers check but my function miserably fails with negatives

```
function findD(arr) {

    myArr = arr.sort((a, b) => b - a);

    for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {

        for (var k = i + 1; k < myArr.length - 2; k++) {

            var j = k + 1,
                d = myArr.length - 1;

            while (j < d) {

                let sum = myArr[k] + myArr[j] + myArr[d];

                if (sum == myArr[i]) {
                    return myArr[i];
                } else if (sum < myArr[i]) {
                    d--;
                } else if (sum > myArr[i]) {
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

how to handle negative values in the array?

Comment: Were any of these answers satisfactory? If so, please mark one with an accepted checkmark and upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's imagine there's an array like `[-2, -1, 0, 3]`.

Then, after sorting it in the descending order as per your algorithm it will be `[3, 0, -1, -2]`. Obviously, your algorithm will pick only `3` as you assume `d` must be larger than numbers at the remaining `3` positions. That's wrong, of course. You shouldn't assume that `a`, `b` and `c` are necessarily less than `d`. That's why you must check other cases when `d` occupies all possible positions in relation to `a,b,c`. So, first consider a brute force approach that will have `O(n^4)` time and `O(1)` space complexity:

```
...
for (var i = myArr.length; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    for (var k = 0; k < myArr.length; k++) {
        if (k == i) {
            continue
        }
        for (var j = k + 1; j < myArr.length; j++) {
            if (j == i) {
                continue
            }
            for (var d = j + 1; d < myArr.length; d++) {
                if (d == i) {
                    continue
                }
                if (myArr[i] == myArr[k] + myArr[j] + myArr[d]) {
                    return myArr[i]
                }     
            }
        }
    }
}
return null 
...
```

But this problem can be solved in `O(n^2)` time and `O(n^2)` space.

First we should realise that `a + b = d - c`.

So, for the given array `arr` and every pair of indices `i,j: i<j` we store `arr[i] + arr[j]` (`a + b`) as a key and pair `i,j` as an item of a value (the value is a list of pairs of indices) in `sumsMap`. The value must be a list because there can be several pairs of indices corresponding to the same sum `a + b`.

Then, go through each pair of indices again `k,l` and check if a key `arr[l] - arr[k]` (`d - c`) or `arr[k] - arr[l]` (`c - d`) exists in `sumsMap`. If it does and indices `l,k` are different from the ones in `sumsMap[s]` then update the maximum element if it's lower than `arr[l]`.

```js
function solve(arr) {
    var sumsMap = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            var sum = arr[i] + arr[j]
            
            // several pairs of indices can correspond to the same summ so keep all of them
            var mappedIndices = sumsMap[sum]
            if (typeof mappedIndices == "undefined") {
                mappedIndices = []
            }
            let pair = {}
            pair.first = i
            pair.second = j
            mappedIndices.push(pair)
            
            sumsMap[sum] = mappedIndices
        }
    }    

    var maxD = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
    for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        for (var l = 0; l < arr.length; l++) {
            mappedIndices = sumsMap[arr[l] - arr[k]]
            
            if (mappedIndices != undefined) {
                // in the worst case, 4 pairs of indices may contain k or l but the fifth one won't as numbers in the array are unique and hence the same index can occur only twice 
                var steps = Math.min(5, mappedIndices.length)
                for (var s = 0; s < steps; s++) {
                    var pair = mappedIndices[s]
                    if (pair.first != k && pair.first != l && pair.second != k && pair.second != l) {
                        maxD = Math.max(maxD, arr[l])    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (maxD == Number.MIN_VALUE) {
        return -1
    } else {
        return maxD
    }
}

document.write(solve([-100,-1,0,7,101] ))
document.write("<br>")
document.write(solve([-93,-30,-31,-32] ))
```

Answer (score 1):

I translated the function Renaldo suggested from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-largest-d-in-array-such-that-a-b-c-d/ to JavaScript for you.

```
function findLargestd(S, n){ 
    var found = false;

    // sort the array in 
    // ascending order 
    S.sort((a, b) => a - b); 

    // iterating from backwards to 
    // find the required largest d 
    for(var i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--){ 
        for(var j = 0; j < n; j++){ 

            // since all four a, b, c,  
            // d should be distinct 
            if(i == j){
                continue;
            } 

            for(var k = j + 1; k < n; k++){ 
                if(i == k){
                    continue;
                }

                for(var l = k + 1; l < n; l++){ 
                    if(i == l){
                        continue;
                    } 

                    // if the current combination   
                    // of j, k, l in the set is  
                    // equal to S[i] return this  
                    // value as this would be the  
                    // largest d since we are   
                    // iterating in descending order  
                    if(S[i] == S[j] + S[k] + S[l]){ 
                        found = true; 
                        return S[i]; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    //if not found, return 0
    if(found === false){
        return 0; 
    }
}
```